# How can I combine a product attribute with a subset of another one in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce, database

Assume I have 2 product attributes (using the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/) module):

1. **Background color** (white, black, green, blue, yellow).
2. **Surface** (glossy or matte).

And assume that surface "glossy" can be only selected in combination with background color "white" or "black".

How should I configure this conbination of attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Required steps

#### Step 1

Create 2 taxonomies:

1. Background color, with terms white, black, green, blue, yellow
2. Surface, with terms glossy or matte.

#### Step 2

For each prod type, add field "Background color", which is a field "term referenace" (and refer to the Background color taxonomy).

Attentionn: make sure to check the option "attribute field settings" (enables this field to function as an attribute field on the add-to-cart-form).

Then add a similar term reference field "Surface".

#### Step 3

Use `store / products / add product` to add individual products, with a specific SKU, and for which you pick the right values for each of both taxonomies.

So for "Matte surface", you should create 5 individual products (one for each background color). But for "Glossy surface", you only create 2 individual products (1 with a white background color, and 1 with a black background color)

## Video tutorials

For a more detailed video tutorial of the steps described above, refer to [Drupal Commerce - Pruduct Attributes](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=i8wUo7r9a-I) (16:13). Before doing so, you may want to first view these related videos:

- [Drupal Commerce - Pruduct Types](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=d6RSQXMI81M) (9:11).
- [Drupal Commerce - Pruduct Displays](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EnOf5AFBA7k) (11:36).

By only reviewing/studying these 3 videos (total time = about 37 mins), you'll have a very good foundation to get started with the fundamentals of Drupal Commerce.

## Commerce Backoffice

Managing products (and orders) can be confusing. However, the [Commerce Backoffice](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice) module helps with that. For more details about that module, refer to my answer to the question about
[Correct way for Attributes in Commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165678/correct-way-for-attributes-in-commerce/165716#165716)

Comment: Perfect as always...
Yeah, I already watched these views a couple of times, but you know, something some tiny bit of explanation is required to get it 100%.
Thank you!

Comment: Merci (again), aka "Thank you". Just so you know: nobody is perfect, and my name is not "nobody" ... Anyway, let e go find your "next question" to work on ... may I?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Always wanted to tell you. I admire your willingness to help :) Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: @AjitS ... euh ... not sure what to reply to your comment, something like "merci for the kudos"? Or am I still missing "something"?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens hah! That should do it.