# How can I let a user select my Drupal Commerce product to either be shipped or downloaded?

Tags: 7, commerce, files

I am using the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module. I want to download the digital file. I am using the [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) and [Commerce File](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_file) modules.

But now I need to add an option to let the user select between **Shippable** or **Download**. If the user selects *Shippable*, the product will be shipped, while if the user selects *Download*, the user will be able to download the file.

I want to do it like in the product page:

- If the user selects **Shippable**, the user doesn't have a FILES tab in the User profile page.
- If the user selects **Download**, the user has a FILES tab in the User profile page.

  [image: I want to do it like in the product page.]

How can I implement this using **Drupal Commerce**?.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Required steps

#### Step 1

Create a taxonomy, let's say it's called "*Delivery methods*", with terms "*Shipable*" and "*Download*".

#### Step 2

For each product type, add a field like "*Delivery method*", which is a field "term reference" (and refer to the "*Delivery methods*" taxonomy).

Attentionn: make sure to check the option "attribute field settings" (enables this field to function as an attribute field on the add-to-cart-form).

#### Step 3

Use `store / products / add product` to add individual products, with a specific SKU, and for which you pick the right values for the Delivery methods taxonomy.

## Video tutorials

For a more detailed video tutorial of the steps described above, refer to [Drupal Commerce - Pruduct Attributes](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=i8wUo7r9a-I) (16:13).

Before doing so, you may want to first view these related videos:

- [Drupal Commerce - Pruduct Types](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=d6RSQXMI81M) (9:11).
- [Drupal Commerce - Pruduct Displays](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EnOf5AFBA7k) (11:36).

By only reviewing/studying these 3 videos (total time = about 37 mins), you'll have a very good foundation to get started with the fundamentals of Drupal Commerce.

## Commerce Backoffice

Managing products (and orders) can be confusing. However, the [Commerce Backoffice](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice) module helps with that. For more details about that module, refer to my answer to the question about
[Correct way for Attributes in Commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165678/correct-way-for-attributes-in-commerce/165716#165716).